# Fetch the specific number of time series data from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, time-series

Obviously when dealing with time-series data which relates to some natural partition key like sensor id it can be used as a primary key. But what to do if we are interested in a global view and there is no natural candidate for the partition key? If we model the schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_data(
 year smallint,
 day smallint,
 date timestamp,
 value text
 PRIMARY KEY ((year, day), timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC);
```

It is (probably) going to work just fine for most cases but given we know what year and days to fetch.

What if we don't care what day is it but we expect to see first 50 most recent items? What if we then want to see next 50 items? Is there a way to do it in Cassandra? What is the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a 2nd table of the year/days. When reading can grab from it first. When adding to my_data update that as well but keep a cache of days inserted so each app would only try the insert once per day. ie for example adding extra key so can have multiple streams not just a single table per time series:

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (
  key blob,
  year smallint,
  day smallint,
  date timestamp,
  value text
  PRIMARY KEY ((key, year, day), timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC);

CREATE TABLE my_data_keys (
   key blob,
   year smallint,
   day smallint,
   PRIMARY KEY ((key), year, day)
)
```

For inserts:

```
INSERT INTO my_data_keys (key, year, day) VALUES (0x01, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO my_data ...
```

Then keep a in memory Set somewhere that you stored that key/year/data so you dont need to insert it every time. To read most recent:

```
SELECT year, day FROM my_data_keys WHERE key = 0x01;
```

driver returns iterator, for each element in it make query to my_data until 50 records reached.

If inserts are frequent enough can just work backwards from "today", issuing queries until you get 50 events. If data sparse though that can be a lot of wasted reads and another table work better.

Comment: Could you please provide a schema and queries depicting this idea? I have trouble understanding how this second table would help.

Comment: Does this mean that if there are - say - only 1 entry per a sequence of days I would need to sequentially query Cassandra 50 times? Should I be keeping the number of entries as well and increment that atomically as I do (asynchronous) insert to the date table?

Comment: yes. If your data is that sparse though, dont use day for your bucketing but month